# Link in fixed content not working when scrolled on mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile-safari, css-position

I've been checking several threads and questions that seemed similar to my current problem but actually wasn't able to find a solution that worked for my case.

I'm currently developing a mobile website which can be found under http://dev.sturbock.me.
The page does have a fixed header with some sub menus beneath it.

As long as the whole page is scrolled all the way up to the top, everything works fine just as expected. Now once you scroll down a bit, open the Menu and try to click one of the links, nothing will happen.

Has anyone of you guys had a similar problem of knows how to fix this? Probably a really easy one but this just got me stuck for a few hours.

Really appreciate your support! Thanks!

Marcel

Comment: tried in FF and the menu drops down, I clicked lifestyle, then clicked the menu icon again, the menu will not disappear. I tried it to open the page on ios6 simulator, menu is working the same as in FF

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Fixed this issue.